# python: How to read a file and store each line using map function?

Tags: python-3.x, file, map-function

I'm trying to reconvert a program that I wrote but getting rid of all for loops. 
The original code reads a file with thousands of lines that are structured like:
Ex. 2 lines of a file:

[image]

As you can see, the first line starts with LPPD;LEMD and the second line starts with DAAE;LFML. I'm only interested in the very first and second element of each line.

The original code I wrote is:

```
# Libraries
import sys
from collections import Counter
import collections
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
import time

# START

# @time=0 
start = time.time()

# Defining default program argument
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    fileName = "file.txt"
else:
    fileName = sys.argv[1]

takeOffAirport = []
landingAirport = []

# Reading file
lines = 0 # Counter for file lines
try:
    with open(fileName) as file:
        for line in file:
            words = line.split(';')
            # Relevant data, item1 and item2 from each file line
            origin = words[0]
            destination = words[1]
            # Populating lists
            landingAirport.append(destination)
            takeOffAirport.append(origin)
            lines += 1
except IOError:
    print ("\n\033[0;31mIoError: could not open the file:\033[00m %s" %fileName)

airports_dict = defaultdict(list)

# Merge lists into a dictionary key:value
for key, value in chain(Counter(takeOffAirport).items(), 
                    Counter(landingAirport).items()):
    # 'AIRPOT_NAME':[num_takeOffs, num_landings]
    airports_dict[key].append(value) 
# Sum key values and add it as another value
for key, value in airports_dict.items():
    #'AIRPOT_NAME':[num_totalMovements, num_takeOffs, num_landings]
    airports_dict[key] = [sum(value),value]  

# Sort dictionary by the top 10  total movements
airports_dict = sorted(airports_dict.items(), 
                        key=lambda kv:kv[1], reverse=True)[:10]
airports_dict = collections.OrderedDict(airports_dict)

# Print results 
print("\nAIRPORT"+ "\t\t#TOTAL_MOVEMENTS"+ "\t#TAKEOFFS"+ "\t#LANDINGS")
for k in airports_dict:
    print(k,"\t\t", airports_dict[k][0],
      "\t\t\t", airports_dict[k][1][1],
      "\t\t", airports_dict[k][1][0])


# @time=1
end = time.time()- start
print("\nAlgorithm execution time: %0.5f" % end)
print("Total number of lines read in the file: %u\n" % lines)
airports_dict.clear
takeOffAirport.clear
landingAirport.clear
```

My goal is to simplify the program using map, reduce and filter. So far I have sorted teh creation of the two independent lists, one for each first element of each file line and another list with the second element of each file line by using:

```
# Creates two independent lists with the first and second element from each line
takeOff_Airport = list(map(lambda sub: (sub[0].split(';')[0]), lines))
landing_Airport = list(map(lambda sub: (sub[0].split(';')[1]), lines))
```

I was hoping to find the way to open the file and achieve the exact same result as the original code by been able to opemn the file thru a map() function, so I could pass each list to the above defined maps; takeOff_Airport and landing_Airport.

Comment: If our answers don't apply, you're going to need to be more clear about what you're trying to do. It seems like you want to replace a manual loop with a (slightly) more efficient `map` that produces the same result, but the description is funny (the second argument to `map` is an iterable of things to pass as arguments to the mapper function; the mapper function is called with one such argument and `map` yields the value returned by the mapper; it makes no sense to pass a single file name as the iterable to process). Perhaps you're trying to call `readFile` over and over with many file names?

Comment: Your proposed solution is actually worse than what you already have. What you already have lazily iterates the file, extracting both things you need at once, throwing away the line when you're done, so peak memory usage only involves the data you need. Your proposed solution would require loading the entire file into memory, and ripping through it twice, doing the same work twice over. Beyond that, if you need a `lambda` to use `map`, you're not "simplifying" anything; it's slower and uglier than an equivalent list comprehension or generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

So if we have a file as such

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

and we do like this

```
open(file_name).read().split('\n')
```

we get this

```
['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', '']
```

Is this what you wanted?

**Edit 1**

I feel this is somewhat reduntant but since map applies a function to each element of an iterator we will have to have our file name in a list, and we ofcourse define our function

```
def open_read(file_name):
    return open(file_name).read().split('\n')

print(list(map(open_read, ['test.txt'])))
```

This gets us

```
>>> [['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', '']]
```

Comment: No, this is somehow what I'm already doing with the readFile(fileName) function. What I want is to be able to read a file using the map(functionToReadFile, fileName).

Answer (score 0):

So first off, calling `split('\n')` on each line is silly; the line is guaranteed to have at most one newline, at the end, and nothing after it, so you'd end up with a bunch of `['all of line', '']` `list`s. To avoid the empty string, just `strip` the newline. This won't leave each line wrapped in a `list`, but frankly, I can't imagine why you'd *want* a `list` of one-element `list`s containing a single string each.

So I'm just going to demonstrate using `map`+`strip` to get rid of the newlines, [using `operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) to perform the `strip` on each line:

```
from operator import methodcaller

def readFile(fileName):
    try:
        with open(fileName) as file:
            return list(map(methodcaller('strip', '\n'), file))
    except IOError:
      print ("\n\033[0;31mIoError: could not open the file:\033[00m %s" %fileName)
```

Sadly, since your file is context managed (a good thing, just inconvenient here), you do have to `list`ify the result; `map` is lazy, and if you didn't `list`ify before the `return`, the `with` statement would close the file, and pulling data from the `map` object would die with an exception.

To get around that, you can implement it as a trivial generator function, so the generator context keeps the file open until the generator is exhausted (or explicitly `close`d, or garbage collected):

```
def readFile(fileName):
    try:
        with open(fileName) as file:
            yield from map(methodcaller('strip', '\n'), file)
    except IOError:
      print ("\n\033[0;31mIoError: could not open the file:\033[00m %s" %fileName)
```

`yield from` will introduce a tiny amount of overhead over directly iterating the `map`, but not much, and now you don't have to slurp the whole file if you don't want to; the caller can just iterate the result and get a split line on each iteration without pulling the whole file into memory. It does have the slight weakness that opening the file will be done lazily, so you won't see the exception (if there is any) until you begin iterating. This can be worked around, but it's not worth the trouble if you don't really need it.

I'd generally recommend the latter implementation as it gives the caller flexibility. If they want a `list` anyway, they just wrap the call in `list` and get the `list` result (with a tiny amount of overhead). If they don't, they can begin processing faster, and have much lower memory demands.

Mind you, this whole function is fairly odd; replacing `IOError`s with `print`s and (implicitly) returning `None` is hostile to API consumers (they now have to check return values, and can't actually tell what went wrong). In real code, I'd probably just skip the function and insert:

```
with open(fileName) as file:
    for line in map(methodcaller('strip', '\n'), file)):
        # do stuff with line (with newline pre-stripped)
```

inline in the caller; *maybe* define `split_by_newline = methodcaller('split', '\n')` globally to use a friendlier name. It's not *that* much code, and I can't imagine that this specific behavior is needed in that many independent parts of your file, and inlining it removes the concerns about when the file is opened and closed.

Comment: Using your second block of code it works, but only for one of the lists that stores the very first element of each line, not for the second element.